# Traffic generation at higher data rate

Tags: python, network-protocols, packet, scapy, traffic

```
from scapy.all import *
import socket 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 0))
pe=Ether()/IP(src="10.0.0.1",dst="10.0.0.2")/ICMP()
data = pe.build()
while True:
     s.send(data)
```

Though I had mention the destination address but still with this script I got this error

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "testing.py", line 12, in

s.send(data)

socket.error: [Errno 89] Destination address required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `AF_PACKET` instead of `AF_INET`.

   ```
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
   ```
2. Bind to the device name instead of address.

   ```
   s.bind(("lo", 0))
   ```

   (`lo` is loopback device name. Replace it with actual device name if you want to send the packet outside the machine.)

Comment: After doing this when I run the script, it gets stopped after printing this
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
And at keyboard interrupt it gives the the error again 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    s.send(data)
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: I am trying generate trying in Python using scapy. Producing the packet is fine, but when it comes to sending traffic at a sufficiently fast rate (for my needs, somewhere in the range of 500-700 packets per second), I seem to have hit a wall at around 20-30 pps. this is why I used sockets or trying to use.

Comment: @M.HarisAzfar, The code works as expected if I changed your code as I described in the answer. See this screencast I just recorded: http://asciinema.org/a/8277

Comment: The code works now but wireshark not capturing the packets. I dont know the reason because it was capturing when I wasn't using the sockets –